# In App Purchase - Auto Renewal Subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I need to know regarding the payments issue on auto renewal subscriptions.

Lets suppose, if an user subscribed on premium plan, now its has to renewed, but his card is expired or some other issues in user payment method.

How many times iTunes try for payments, is there any limit of failure attempt to charge the money ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think iTunes disclose the retry number (if there is any) but they do eventually give up. Users with expired cards or other payment issues appear under "Billing  issue" category in iTunes Connect cancel report. You can use it to see that iTunes eventually give up and how many users you have with these issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my concern is to disable the premium services if there is no money charged, how to manage this.

Comment: For a user with billing issues, when you validate his recipe you will see that their subscription was expired. Same way you will see it if the user did not renew his subscription by looking at the expiration field in the receipt.  I found this documentation very helpful - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW3

Comment: Hey Just one more question, do we need restore purchase button for auto renew subscriptions ?

Comment: Yes. It is relevant for the case where a user replaced his device for example.